# Google Maps API key not working

Tags: google-maps

I'm having a problem with getting my Google Maps API key to work. I originally had the problem when trying to access http://dev.domain.com using a key generated for http://domain.com, however I subsequently tried generating a key for http://dev.domain.com and it still didn't work.

I get the typical `This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/.` alert message when trying the site. Checking their [FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html) and following it's instructions to `alert(window.location.host)` to check the domain returns `dev.domain.com` which looks correct (unless it's meant to have http:// at the start? In which case I don't see how I've done something wrong).

Both keys (`dev.domain.com` and `domain.com`) work correctly on `localhost`.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can do to solve this or any further tests I can do to work it out?

Comment: That's strange – the Google Maps API documentation says that "Signing up a key for http://yourdomain.com is usually the best practice, as it will work for all subdomains and directories".

Are you sure that you are providing the API key correctly (right keys for the right domains, etc)

Comment: I know it's strange! I spent the better part of an hour copying and pasting and checking what I was doing to make sure that I wasn't missing any characters off the key or anything like that. I'm only accessing dev.domain.com and have tried both keys, both of which failed (when both should have worked).

Comment: I'm just going to use the v3 API since it doesn't require keys. I'll just have to go through and change all of the v2 references to their v3 equivalent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said in my comment I ended up using the v3 API as this never ended up being solvable.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question as I was just now beating my head against this same issue. I finally noticed that the code Google provided for linking to the API was different from what I'd been using. I replaced this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=___">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("maps", "2.x", { "language": "en" });
</script>
```

with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&sensor=false&key=___">
</script>
```

and the error went away.

Comment: Notice that although this uses the V3 syntax for instantiating the api, it doesn't require you to upgrade from v2 to v3 - in my case the upgrade was breaking existing code that I didn't have time to go through and debug, so that was a big plus.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and it turned that i was doing 2 calls to the http://www.google.com/jsapi url. The first one for adsense (without the key parameter) and then the second one for google maps with the key. Pretty stupid mistake but the result is that the although you put the key on the second call it doesn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem and when i look at src part i found that my querystring part of src is wrong.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;&hl=en;key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I clearly typed wrong querystring part. **&\amp;&hl=en;**
I put & to wrong place. Then i changed my wrong syntax with a correct one

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;hl=en&amp;key=MY_API_KEY&amp;sensor=true"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And voila it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps APi not working in Firefox and IE but working in Chrome and Safari

CSS-Bug

Hi everyone, this is slightly off-topic, but since it cost me a whole day to figure this out i want to share it.

I had the above mentioned problem. The maps would load but except for the google log and terms of use, the map was just grey.
SOLUTION

somewhere in a parent css i had following cod:

```
#content * {
    max-width: 100%;                      
}
```

removing it solved the problem;

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After going through their FAQ i found that if we want our subdomains to enable Google map we have to request the API for http://domain.com/ (without www) . it worked for me.
Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks, but I said that I had tried the key generated for http://domain.com and that also didn't work. I never worked out the reason for the problem, instead I just started using v3 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fighting key issues for the last couple of hours.  Was working on localhost, but not on my local network address or a domain name.  I solved the issue by changing v=2 to v=2.x.  I haven't tried 2.s.  Also adding alert(window.location.host) for both my localhost address and domain name to a Browser Key in google's api console for maps v2.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I added line breaks to the src element for readability:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;
v=2&amp;
key=ABQ...BlaBlaBla...cVw"
    type="text/javascript" />
```

Removing the line breaks from the src element solved the problem:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQ...BlaBlaBla...cVw"
    type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: You had a different problem actually.

Comment: You also used a self closing tag, when you should've used an opening tag and a closing tag.