# Google Maps API Key alert

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem with my Google Maps API key. I get an alert saying "`This web site needs a different Google Maps API key.`" When I prees OK to the alert the map are loading and working fine.

The same problem is already posted:
[Google Maps API key not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803327/google-maps-api-key-not-working)

I have tried to request the API key for both "http://www.domain.com" and "http://domain.com" but I still get the alert. 
When I follow the instructions from their FQA and use alert(window.location.host) I get www.domain.com but the api key generator will only accept the domain if the prefix is http://

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that is was a generel encoding error in my google maps api script tag. I got the alert error when I had a script tag like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;amp;v=2&amp;amp;key=MyGoogleMapsApiKey" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem here is the duplicated `amp;`wich was generated from a scriptmanager in asp.net. So the `&` was replaced with `&amp;`.

The script tag should look like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=MyGoogleMapsApiKey" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So if you are using a scriptmanager to add script tags or in any other way dynamically adding script tags to your pages, wach out for duplicated `amp;`.

Comment: You should accept this answer, as it solves the problem stated in the question. Yes, I know it is your own. Happy birthday.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign up for the new google API key for your new domain, I used to get the same error message, because I use the old API with the new domain, please click the following link to register your new API key for the new domain.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Hope this can help.

Vutha

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I remembered that Google calls my Appspot app by a different name found in the Versions area of the App Engine Dashboard.  I changed the name of the URL to the long version and the key started to work... e.g. LIVE URI... http://5.latest.myappname.appspot.com.

You'd think they could resolve their keys to their own app hosting service urls.

Regards,
John