# google map API error.. so annoying

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

the website i developed yields the following error for street view google API:
This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

I have tried to register the API using "www.mydomain.com" and "mydomain.com" but no luck.. any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What domain are you running the map on? Are you 100% sure you have the correct key, without e.g. spaces before or after?

Comment: 100% sure without the space. sorry not too sure with your question here: "What domain are you running the map on"?

Comment: Poor question title, try adding more useful detail to attract more views.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469850/google-maps-api-key-alert-problem

Answer (score 0):

What is your websites address? Are you sure you wrote it correctly while registered for a key?

Also, jsut so you know, he newest version of google maps, version 3 doesn't require a key.

Comment: do you have the link for the version 3?

Comment: here's the documentation for v3: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/